# How to run PyCharm using port 80

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I can't run my PyCharm IDE using port 80.
I need to use PayPal that requires me to use port 80.
But using Mac OS X 10.8 I can't have it working because of permission issues.
I've already tried running PyCharm with SUDO command.

Does anyone know how to run Pycharm using port 80, or any other solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't PyCharm just an IDE? What is it doing on the network?

Comment: @Aesthete The IDE runs the project. The project is the one on port 8000. And I can't change the port in PyCharm due to permission issues as described above. Thanks.

Comment: You need to look into actually setting up Django behind Apache.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/ or look into running with a hosting service like https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django. Don't run a site that's accepting paypal transactions out of your IDE...

Comment: @MikeSteder I'm not. I actually need to change the port set at the IDE so I don't have to run the website outside the IDE. Thanks.

Comment: The IDE should just be feeding the port you supply into the scripts it's running. Unless you plan on running your project in the IDE forever you should probably look at how to do that in the project itself. Unless I'm completely missing the point here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pycharm: run server with root permission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036342/pycharm-run-server-with-root-permission)

Comment: @CrazyCoder could be, but as I said, I alread tried running the IDE with the sudo command with no success.

Comment: How exactly did you run it with the `sudo`? Please post the complete command line. Also consider reverse proxy option as suggested in my answer.

Comment: Doesn't your paypal implementation have a sandbox/debug mode that works with other ports, I have had no problems with this before..

Comment: @Hedde Have you ever worked with PayPal and Django? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try this? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036342/pycharm-run-server-with-root-permission

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve that by setting the **Environment Variable** inside PyCharm IDE.
The Variable will be: `FLASK_RUN_PORT=80`
Steps to achieve that:

1. RUN -> Edit Configurations
2. Environment variables -> `FLASK_RUN_PORT=80`

Image:
[image]

Comment: There is no image.

Answer (score 2):

To give PyCharm permissions, one has to run as Administor (Windows) or using `sudo` if on OSX/Linux: `sudo /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/MacOS/pycharm`.  Note that this truly runs PyCharm as a new user, so you'll have to register the app again and set up your customizations again if you have any (ie theme, server profiles etc)

Answer (score 1):

For the ones who are looking for the answer of this question, please check your Pycharm Run/Debug Configurations. Run->Edit Configurations ->Port

Comment: The idea is that port 80 doesn't work due to permissions - not that they couldn't figure out where to configure the port

Comment: There is no port property in Edit Configurations.

Answer (score 0):

To change the port, add the following option in the Run/Debug Configurations :

[image]

I put 8000 value as 80 doesn't work dur to permissions.